# FileNotFoundError and WebDriverException

Tags: python

I'm trying to run Selenium but got some errors can you help me out?!

FileNotFoundError and WebDriverException error is what i'm facing

```
from selenium import webdriver 
PATH = (r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

I get these errors:

```
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     71             cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
---> 72             self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
     73                                             close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3439d06e3794> in <module>
      3 PATH = (r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
      4 
----> 5 driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
      6 
      7 driver.get("https://drpharmo.com/")

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     79         except OSError as err:
     80             if err.errno == errno.ENOENT:
---> 81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
     83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I was trying to browse using chrome and chrome driver with jupyter notebook and i got these errors.
plz help me out
thanks

Comment: There is very little information to go on. Have you googled and read on the errors? What code are you executing? Easier if you add a code example

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone :)
I got it, I changed file's name earlier and didn't edit the PATh so that's why I got these errors